Schengen visa issued by Germany - Is a layover in Vienna okay before heading to Berlin?
I have a Schengen visa issued by the German embassy, and it clearly states that it's valid for all Schengen states. I have a round-trip flight booked to Berlin, but my itinerary includes a 2-hour layover in Vienna, where I will change flights before continuing to Germany.
The layover in Austria is solely because of the flight itinerary, and I don't plan to visit Austria first. I've read that you are supposed to enter the Schengen area through the country that issued your visa or is your main destination.
Given my layover in Vienna, will I face any issues? Is it okay to have a layover in Austria before heading to Germany, or should I change my flight to enter through Germany directly?

Was that the itinerary you filed when you applied for the visa? There’s no rule forbidding transit on your way to the visa-issuing country, AFAIK.

@Traveller No, it's not the same, cause they changed the duration of my visa (In compare to what I planned and requested) and I can't use the reservation that I gave when I was applying.

As long as the main purpose and itinerary is substantially the same it's good. Flying via another Schengen state doesn't change that.

"I've read that you are supposed to enter the Schengen area through the country that issued your visa or is your main destination": you've read incorrect information.  There is no such requirement.

@phoog unfortunately consulate employees in developing nations often scaremonger applicants about such non-existing requirements. My own grandma is falsely told every time that her visa is only valid for Czech Republic, even though she always gets a multi-entry Schengen visa and therefore no such restriction could be present.

@JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for your answer, but the ticket says this stopover requires a Schengen visa. I also booked my return flight (which also has a stopover in Vienna) earlier to leave there before my visa expires.

@JonathanReez it's entirely possible to issue a visa with limited territorial validity for multiple entries.  The controlling parameter is the text in the "valid for" field.  If it says "Schengen states" (in Czech most likely) then they're lying to her.  If it says "Czechia" or "Czech Republic" then the visa is in fact valid only for the Czech Republic.

@JanusBahsJacquet the flight from Vienna to Berlin is an internal flight.  Regardless of luggage or ticketing it will be necessary to enter the Schengen area in Austria to be able to reach the boarding gate in the Schengen part of the airport from the arrival gate in the non-Schengen part.

@phoog it always said "Schengen states", so the consulate employees were definitely out of line.

@phoog Of course it is – no idea where my mind was last night. Comment deleted.

@JanusBahsJacquet I figured it was something like that :-)

@phoog, JonathanReez: are those employees not simply giving a slightly garbled explanation of the Schengen "main destination" rule?

@smci that may be the origin of their comments, but if it is then it is so "garbled" as to be outright incorrect.  The main destination rule determines which country should process a visa application and issue the visa, or rather is part of that determination, but, once issued, a "Schengen states" visa is valid for all Schengen states.  Aside from the trip or trips described in the application, there is no requirement even to visit the issuing country on other trips.

For example, suppose @JonathanReez's grandmother has a 5-year multiple-entry visa from the Czech Republic because she regularly visits relatives there.  Now suppose that during the second year of that visa's validity she wants to fly directly to some other Schengen country for a one-off visit.  One purpose of the Schengen uniform visa system is to enable her to use her existing multiple-entry visa for that trip, reducing the administrative burden for Schengen member states' consulates (and for travelers).  Would those employees have her get a second visa? She'd have to cancel the first.

You write:

I've read that you are supposed to enter the Schengen area through the country that issued your visa or is your main destination.

Not sure where you read that, but it’s incorrect. You can enter the Schengen Area wherever you want. Consider the case of people travelling by ground transportation (train, bus, car…): they evidently won’t be able to enter directly a Schengen country which does does not have an external border on the direction you are coming from (for instance someone coming from Turkey, travelling to Germany, will have to go through quite a few other Schengen countries on the way).
What is important is that you actually visit the country which issued the visa and that it remains your main destination (in number of days, even though the law says otherwise). Some countries (mostly East-European countries) seem to be very strict on you staying in their country the number of days you said you would in your application and monitor hotel cancellations/changes, but I don't think that applies to Germany, and it doesn't apply to your current travel plans either.
Border guards may ask questions, but just showing your ticket to Germany (or your boarding pass which you will probably have at that point) should be enough for this topic. There are of course other rules to obey and matching questions and proof, but the point of entry isn’t an issue.

"Not sure where you read that, but it’s incorrect." - I agree it's formally incorrect, but is it may be still the least cumbersome way? If you enter in the country that issued the visa, possibly there might be less questions asked about whether you are actually in transit to the issuing country. From what I have heard, it seems to have become common in business trips to enter via a Schengen country A that issued the visa, even though the trip leads to country B (whose consulate could not issue the visa in time, or whose consulate had reached the annual maximum of visas to grant, or other ...

... such reasons why the visa was not obtained via country B in the first place).

@O.R.Mapper border officers in Vienna know that Austrian Airlines is part of the Lufthansa group and that lots of people fly through Vienna to reach Germany, and they know the main destination rule.  Furthermore, in this case those officers will be staffing the desk that checks passengers transferring to flights to other Schengen-area airports.  The situation you describe is a way of minimizing the chance of being found out after submitting a false application to get around the main destination rule; someone who has complied with the rule does not have to worry about that.

Let me share a personal anecdote.
I had a conference in Czech Republic and I obtained a Shengen visa, from Czech Republic embassy. I entered via FrankFurt (Germany), traveled to Berlin, stayed a couple of days with friends. Then proceeded to Czech republic, via train and spent 5 days there. Afterwards, I took a flight to Paris, stayed 3 days there and exited the Schengen area.
My country -> Germany -> Czech Republic (Main destination) -> France -> My country
I carried a printed itenary, along with the train and flight tickets, accommodation bookings. I was never asked why I am not entering Czech Republic directly and returning from there, by anyone.
Your case is a straight forward one. You have boarding pass to next destination. Just show it, if asked.
